# Sobrescribir método CompareTo() en la misma clase

Tags: java

!Buenas!

Estoy realizando unas pruebas con la interfaz `Comparable`, y necesito en una clase tener dos métodos, los cuales **ordenen por precio** y por **metros cuadrados**.

Tengo una **clase Casa** donde tiene sus métodos y atributos, y de esta heredan varios tipos de casas, bien, pues en **Casa** implemento la interfaz `Comparable`y ya he creado el método `compareTo()`para ordenar por precio, pero, ¿Como hago otro método en la misma clase para que ordene por los metros, y en el `main` al utilizar el `sort`, lo diferencie?

He creado el metodo de esta forma:

```
    public int compareTo(Casa o) {

    int resultado = 0;

    if(this.metrosCuadrados < o.getMetrosCuadrados()) {

        resultado = -1;

    }else if(this.metrosCuadrados > o.getMetrosCuadrados()){

        resultado = 1;

    }else {

        resultado = 0;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Pero claro, no puedo crear otro método del mismo nombre, y necesito crear otro tipo de comparacion para los metros.

Comment: Casa debe implementar el metodo compareTo con el metodo de ordenacion por defecto y luego cada clase hija deberia sobreescribir su propio metodo compareTo si es diferente del de por defecto.

Comment: Lo que necesito hacer es un "menú" en el `main` (que ya tengo realizado) donde el usuario elije que los datos mostrados puedan ser ordenados por precio, o por metros, o sin ordenar. Entonces no hace nada diferente en las demás clases.

Comment: Con esa información la cosa cambia. Te he dejado la respuesta de como debe ser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La interfaz `Comparable` unicamente te va a dar una forma de comparar. Para lo que quieres tienes que crear un  `Comparator` para cada opción

```
// Para metros cuadrados
Collections.sort(listaCasas,new Comparator<Casa>(){
                 public int compare(Casa c1,Casa c2){
                       return c1.getMetrosCuadrados().compareTo(c2.getMetrosCuadrados())
                 }});

// Para precio
Collections.sort(listaCasas,new Comparator<Casa>(){
                 public int compare(Casa c1,Casa c2){
                       return c1.getPrecio().compareTo(c2.getPrecio())
                 }});
```